# How to print csv rows in ascending order Python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I am trying to read a csv file, and parse the data and return on row (start_date) only if the date is before September 6, 2010. Then print the corresponding values from row (words) in ascending order. I can accomplish the first half using the following:

```
import csv

with open('sample_data.csv', 'rb') as f:

read = csv.reader(f, delimiter =',')

for row in read:

    if row[13] <= '1283774400':
        print(row[13]+"\t \t"+row[16])
```

It returns the correct start_date range, and corresponding word column values, but they are not returning in ascending order which would display a message if done correctly.

I have tried to use the sort() and sorted() functions, after creating an empty list to populate then appending it to the rows, but I am just not sure where or how to incorporate that into the existing code, and have been terribly unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to sort it, I mean you want sorted data for word column values?

Comment: I want to return the data from the start_date column if the date in the rows are less than or equal to September 6, 2010. Then return the data from the words column that meets the condition. I can return the correct rows from the columns but I can't print the data in ascending order. I am trying to use sort() or sorted() to print ascending, but it does not print the correct rows or columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the list, filter the list according to the `< date` criteria and sort it according to the 13th row *as integer*

Note that the common mistake would be to filter as ASCII (which may appear to work), but integer conversion is relaly required to avoid sort problems.

```
import csv

with open('sample_data.csv', 'r') as f:
    read = csv.reader(f, delimiter =',')
    # csv has a title, we have to skip it (comment if no title)
    title_row = next(read)
    # read csv and filter out to keep only earlier rows
    lines = filter(lambda row : int(row[13]) < 1283774400,read)

# sort the filtered list according to the 13th row, as numerical
slist = sorted(lines,key=lambda row : int(row[13]))

# print the result, including title line
for row in title_row+slist:
    #print(row[13]+"\t \t"+row[16])
    print(row)
```

Comment: I am getting an error message when running this script. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'start_date'. The actual excel file uses 'start_date' as its id for the column

Comment: that's the point of my commented line: skip title like like this: `title_row = next(read)`. Have edited my post so title line is taken into account.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the code to skip title, but I am getting another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 2, in <module>
    print(row[13]+"\t \t"+row[16])
IndexError: string index out of range ( I am not sure if this is an indentation issue or what, I believe I am indenting correctly, using IDLE 2.7.10

Comment: there may exist some rows in your code which are too short. I just comented out your original statement, and just printed the whole row. Since I don't have your original file, I cannot check by myself.